# Twitter OAuth Login Page on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, twitter, twitter-oauth, sharekit

I have Twitter integrated into my application, with the help of Sharekit. Everything works pretty well except, if the user happens to tap on the "Sign Up" link on the Login/allow page, it goes to a non-sign up error page. Either a "Sorry that page doesn't exist" or "Hold up! Sorry the profile you were trying to view was suspended due to strange activity."

The account I'm using is working as far as logging in, posting etc. But that link seems to go off into space. Also if I click on the "Twitter Gear"/Application Icon the dialog (web view with the Twitter OAuth Authorize page loaded) just closes.

I can't find anything about how to configure stuff like this and everything else seemed to work pretty easily. The closest reference I could find was,this link [Twitter API Issue 1045](http://code.google.com/p/twitter-api/issues/detail?id=1045&can=1&q=iPhone%20oauth%20sign%20up&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Summary%20Opened%20Modified%20Component)

Thanks in Advance for any help

Update:
I've been checking a few other apps with Twitter support. Most of the ones I've checked (TUAW,Joystiq,TFLN) seem to have rolled their own Twitter Login Page (using XAuth I assume) the one I found that uses the Twitter OAuth page (Shazam) actually takes you to mobile Safari and it exhibits the same behavior. Maybe I need to roll my own login?

Comment: Since the Twitter website went down quite often. Is it possible that this was caused by the not-responding twitter server, not by your app?

Comment: This behavior has been consistent. The Sign Up link has never worked, even though the log in has.

Comment: We use our own login pages as well. Seems like an issue in the webpage ShareKit opens. Maybe you can check their code and change the URL to point to the correct one (if it is a twitter url or a custom web page)

Comment: What version of shareKit are you using? Mine seems OK with the sign up link and other links.

Comment: i donot what the problem is but make sure your Date and time are set with respect to your location and region. Once i am facing the similer error when i am integrating twitter in my app and the problem is in Date and time setting my ("Set Date and time automaticlly" is not checked

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you go into the ShareKit class files, go to the two .m files that have "twitter authorization" (im not sure which of the two it is, a simple search on xcode should find it) and change the invalid url that it is being sent to to this URL: https://mobile.twitter.com/signup

That should fix your problem!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest [using a packet sniffer](http://blog.jerodsanto.net/2009/06/sniff-your-iphones-network-traffic/) on your device to determine the exact URL being called when you click the "Sign Up" link. There are plenty of ways to do this, but it is easier on jailbroken phones. Armed with the URL, you can see if it is potentially something you are doing wrong or indeed a twitter bug.

Answer (score 0):

Try Jan Rain it makes it easy to integrate this functionality without errors.

http://www.janrain.com/products/engage/mobile

Comment: Interesting although a little expensive.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a ShareKit folk I am using: https://github.com/baotuo/ShareKit

It looks do not have your issues and have much more improvement. You should give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

When you implement twitter integration, you should not use the library which you used in older projects but download new twitter library. I had some problems with twitter oauth when I used older library. But after download and use new library, the issue was fixed.